# keep expanding a bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, cat

imagine we have n months, here say n=3

I would like to keep adding integer 1, 2, 3 into a shell variable called $test:

so when we do

```
cat $test
```

it will return

```
1 2 3
```

Any idea?

Comment: `myvar=$(echo {1..3})`?

Comment: `cat $test` probably isn't what you want -- that will attempt to display files named 1, 2, and 3. perhaps `echo "$test"`?

Answer (score 1):

Just find a solution:

```
for ((i=1;i<=3; i++));

do

test1="${i}"

test+="$test1 "

done
```

Comment: Why the "test1" variable? Otherwise, +1 for `+=`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ n=3
$ for((i=1; i<=n; i++)) do test="${test} $i"; done
$ echo "$test"
1 2 3
```